# Sales tax report adding order amount

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, sales, reports

I am confused on how to create a report on sales tax in magento.

I see only one report under reports -> sales -> tax but this is missing the actual order amount. When I submit my sales tax I need to put in the total sales not just the sales tax collected.

Is there a way to add this column to the report? What do other people use for sales tax reporting?

thank you for your time

Comment: Why not use Reports > Sales > Orders, which include taxes and order amounts?

Comment: Yeah I looked at that, but I only need the tax from my local state.

Comment: I also need the same feature, adding new column in tax report that shows the order total on which the tax amount is implemented. Please share the solution if you have? @Jared